# How to change the background-color of a Gtk.InfoBar to yellow?

Tags: css, python-2.7, windows-10, gtk3, msys2

The default background color seems to be blue (from the Adwaita theme), even if I set the type of message to Warning. I prefer using CSS.

**`example.py`**:

```
# coding=utf-8

import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk

w = Gtk.Window()
ib = Gtk.InfoBar()

w.add(ib)
w.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)

provider = Gtk.CssProvider()
provider.load_from_path("style.css")

w.get_style_context()\
     .add_provider(provider, Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER)

w.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

**`style.css`**:

```
infobar {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

**Screenshot**:

[image: Screenshot with the problem]

I use Python 2.7.13 and GTK+ 3.22 on Windows 10 with all the updates installed and through MSYS2 with all the updates installed with `pacman -Syyu`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Python Gtk API](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/InfoBar.html#class-details):

> Gtk.InfoBar has a single CSS node with name infobar. The node may get
>   one of the style classes .info, .warning, .error or .question,
>   depending on the message type.

By default, Gtk.InfoBar message type is Gtk.MessageType.INFO and your **`style.css`** file should be, eg.:

```
infobar.info {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

This way you can be more specific to the message type your are setting but `infobar` by itself will also work. The advantage is that you can have custom settings for each message type using `infobar.<messagetype>`.

**EDIT:**

change the widget that will receive the css class to the Gtk.InfoBar instance:

```
ib.get_style_context()\
     .add_provider(provider, Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER)
```

**EDIT 2:**

To add a CssProvider (StyleProvider) as a whole to the application you have the Gdk.Screen class method `Gdk.Screen.add_provider_for_screen` (more [info here](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/StyleContext.html#class-details))

Changing your code to reflect these changes, you'll have:

```
# coding=utf-8

import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

w = Gtk.Window()
ib = Gtk.InfoBar()

w.add(ib)
w.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)

provider = Gtk.CssProvider()
provider.load_from_path("style.css")

Gtk.StyleContext.add_provider_for_screen(Gdk.Screen.get_default (), provider, Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION)

w.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: @silviubogan Sorry, i forgot to set the widget. Check the edit.

Comment: It works! But I want to have a global CSS file for my entire program. How can I do this if the tehnique explained by you is to associate for each widget I want to style an entire CSS file?